# Perl pattern matching in Python

Tags: python

I am a Perl user for many years and started Python recently.

I learned that there is always "one obvious way" to do certain things. I wish to check the "one" way to translate my coding style in Perl below into Python. Thanks!

The objective is to:

- Detect the existance of the pattern
- If found, extract certain portion of the pattern

Perl:

```
if ($str =~ /my(pat1)and(pat2)/) {
    my ($var1, $var2) = ($1, $2);
}
```

As far as I had learn for Python, below is how I am coding now. It seems to be taking more steps than Perl. That's why I have doubt about my Python code.

```
mySearch = re.search ( r'my(pat1)and(pat2)', str )
if mySearch:
    var1 = mySearch.group(1)
    var2 = mySearch.group(2)
```

Comment: `var1, var2 = mySearch.group(1), mySearch.group(2)`

Comment: If you will be using the same pattern a lot, it may make sense to use `re.compile` and give the pattern a variable name.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The one line assignment is useful.

Comment: Thanks @soon for helping to correct my markdown syntax in my question. This is my very first virgin post in StackO :)

Comment: You are always welcome

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't prioritize pattern matching and string manipulation like perl does. These are analogous patterns, and yeah, Python's is longer (it's also got a lot of great things going for it, like the fact it's OOP and doesn't use weird magical global variables).

For the record though, you can be using tuple unpacking to make this more succinct:

```
var1, var2 = mySearch.groups()
```

**Update:**

#### Tuple unpacking

Tuple unpacking is a useful feature in Python. To understand it, let's first ask, what is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). A tuple is, at its heart, an immutable sequence -- unlike with a list, you cannot append or pop or any of that stuff. Syntactically, it's very simple to declare a tuple -- it's just a few values separated by commas.

```
my_tuple = "I", "am", "awesome"
my_tuple[0]  # "I"
my_tuple[1]  # "am"
my_tuple[2]  # "awesome"
```

People often think a tuple is in fact defined by surrounding parentheses -- `my_tuple = ("I", "am", "awesome")` -- but this is wrong; the parentheses are only useful insofar as they clarify or enforce a certain order of operations.

Tuple unpacking is one of the sweetest features in Python. You define a tuple data structure containing undefined names on the left, and you unpack the `iterable` on the right into it. The right side can contain *any* kind of `iterable`, but the shape of its contained data must exactly match the tuple structure of names on the left.

```
# some_var and other_var are both undefined
print some_var  # NameError: some_var is undefined
print other_var  # NameError: other_var is undefined
my_iterable = ["so", "cool"]

# note that 'some_var, other_var' looks a whole lot like a tuple
some_var, other_var = my_iterable
print some_var  # "so"
print other_var  # "cool"
```

Again, we don't need a list on the right but any kind of iterable -- for example, a generator:

```
def some_generator():
     yield 1
     yield 2
     yield 3

a, b, c = some_generator()
print a  # 1
print b  # 2
print c  # 3
```

You can even do tuple unpacking with nested data structures.

```
nested_list = [1, [2, 3], 4]
# note that parentheses are necessary here to delimit tuples
a, (b, c), d = nested_list
```

If the iterable on the right *doesn't* match the pattern on the left, things blow up:

```
# THESE EXAMPLES DON'T WORK
a, b = [1, 2, 3]  # ValueError: too many values to unpack
a, b = []  # ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Actually, this noisy failure makes tuple unpacking my favorite way to get an item from an `iterable` when I think that `iterable` should only have one item in it and I want my code to fail if it has more than one.

```
# note that the left side below is how you define a tuple of one  
bank_statement, = bank_statements  # we def want to blow up if too many statements
```

#### Multiple Assignment

What people think of as multiple assignment is actually just plain tuple unpacking.

```
a, b = 1, 2
print a  # 1
print b  # 2
```

This is nothing special. The interpreter evaluates the right hand side of the equation as a `tuple` -- remember, a tuple is just values (literals, variables, evaluated function calls, whatever) separated by a commas -- and then the interpreter matches it against the left side, just like it did with all the examples above.

#### Bringing it on home

I wrote this to explain the two different answers you were getting for this problem:

```
var1, var2 = mySearch.group(1), mySearch.group(2)
```

and

```
var1, var2 = mySearch.groups()
```

First, recognize that these two statements, for your situation -- where `mySearch` is a `MatchObject` resulting from a regex with two matching groups -- are entirely functionally equivalent.

They differ only very slightly in terms of the nature of the tuple unpacking. The first one declares a tuple on the right while the second uses the tuple returned by `MatchObject.groups`.

This does not really apply to your situation, but it might be useful to understand that `MatchObject.group` and `MatchObject.groups` have slightly different behavior (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group)). `MatchObject.groups` returns all the 'subgroups' -- i.e. capturing groups -- that the regex encounters while `MatchObject.group` returns an individual group and counts the entire pattern as a group accessible at 0.

In reality, for this situation, you should use whichever of these two you think is most expressive or clearest. I personally think mentioning groups 1 and 2 on the right side is redundant and I am constantly annoyed by the fact that `MatchObject.groups(0)` returns the string matched by the entire pattern, thus offsetting all the 'subgroups' to one-indexing.

Comment: Thanks. Are u sure ur code is correct? Should it be the following instead? <br/> `var1, var2 = mySearch.group(1), mySearch.group(2)`. Btw, may I know how do I do a linebreak inside a comment?

Comment: Yes, @tecx, I'm positive -- please see my much expanded explanation above. I'm not sure how to put line breaks inside of comments.

Comment: thank you so so much for ur detail explanation. I wish I can give u an 'up' for ur answer but I couldn't given my 'reputation' here. Apparently, I missed out reading the 's' in the 'groups()' and 'group(#)' method. Now it make sense to me that `var1, var2 = mySearch.groups()` won't return `group(0)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Python you could do more than one variable assignments in a single line with comma as a delimiter.

```
var1, var2 = mySearch.group(1), mySearch.group(2)
```

Other answers says about tuple unpacking. So that would be better if you want to extract all the captured group contents to variables. If you want to grab particular groups contents, you must need to go for the method I mentioned.

```
va1, var2, var3 = mySearch.group(2), mySearch.group(3), mySearch.group(1)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "foobarbuzzlorium"
>>> m = re.search(r'(foo)(bar.*)(lorium)', x)
>>> if m:
        x, y = m.group(1), m.group(3)
        print(x,y)


foo lorium
```

Comment: All of these examples are tuple unpacking. I don't understand what you mean by grabbing particular group contents in this context. Can you explain?

Comment: what if op wants to grab the contents of first two groups only?

Comment: I was hoping to place the `m = re.search(r'my(pat1)and(pat2)', str)` on the `if` statement line, like Perl, to perform the search and grouping at once. But looks like that is not permitted in Python. Anyway, I just want to confirm my understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all groups at once and assign them to variables:

```
var1, var2 = mySeach.groups()
```